# C# Websoct console application keeps closing client session

Tags: c#

I have got a console application which was developed to implement Websocket technology. The application supposed to be listening from biometric finger print device using a socket channel.

This application was given by the manufacturer of the device. So  I have run the application to be listening on a specific port and it seems that the device is connected, however the application seems to be closing client session then printing out in the console the following message ([2020-06-24 14:04:27][Info]Closed[127.0.0.1:58540],Reason:ClientClosing)

Here is the link to the source code  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iXeFB4LjkkkDXirT6FNNsTQ8X9uuCiiy/view

Can you guys please help me out to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: From cmd.exe use >Netstat -a and check status of port 58540. See if there is a listener and/or client after the connection closed and status.   You may be able to tell which initiated the closure.  Also using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler will give details of the closure.

Comment: I have checked, the port is opened

Comment: What do you mean by open?  Have you compared working and after error occurred?

Comment: I have used Hercules software to test the port, and it is connected to the port, which mean no packet loss. I am sure that there is an issue with the application session part that is why I have include a link to the application source code

Comment: Testing port has nothing to do with the Current Status of the port.  Hercules is not telling anything about why the port was closed.  Netstatus tells the status which will sometimes indicate why the port was closed.  To find out why the port closed the sniffer will give information if the closed started from client, server, or from middle of connection.

Comment: I used the command > Netstat -a I can see that port Status is Established and sometimes it is time-wait

Comment: Great.Time-Wait means is the Close ACK did not complete.TCP every action gets an ACK.  So when client closed the server would return an ACK.When the ACK is not received than the Client is in a Time-Wait and still waiting for the ACK.Sometimes referred to the connection being half open and half closed.So new connection will not be allowed to open using the same Source IP, Destination IP, and Port number. The normal reason for this happening to the client and server simultaneously attempted to close connection.  A connection should only be closed by client and never server to prevent this error.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I just want to confirm that the problem is not from the code, because I have gone through the code and I see that the connection is being closed by the client

Comment: What is the server doing?  Is there a race condition between server and client?  Draw a timing diagram that included both client and server so you understand why both client and server are simultaneously closing the connection.